# Why does converting a date to UTC time sometimes remove 1 and sometimes 2 hours?

Tags: javascript, date

The following transforms the date to UTC and, right now, removes 2 hours:

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

The following only removes 1 hour:

```
new Date("2023-01-02 22:00").toISOString()
```

Comment: i dont understand, the current time has nodaylight saving but 22:00 has?!

Comment: Other way around - we are currently in DST where we live

Comment: ahh so it depends on the month then, if its one where da¥light savings exist then the time is different from the wintermonths where it doesnt, correct?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daylight Savings Time where you live

In my country (The Netherlands) starts last Sunday in March at 3am ends last Sunday in October at 2am

The first one below is before, 2nd inside and last one after DST

```js
console.log("\n",
new Date("2023-01-02 22:00").toISOString(),"\n",
new Date("2023-08-22 22:00").toISOString(),"\n", // DST
new Date("2023-11-02 22:00").toISOString(),"\n"
)
```